# How to maintain the Button position when changing the text in code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have a button in my layout with ID `btnsignIn_Master`, and text *"Sign In/Sign Up"*. On a click event I change the text of button, then the alignment of the button changes. How to maintain the alignment even after the text changed?

Below is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/LoginLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/relLayoutMenu"
android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtLoginName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="left|center_horizontal"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Welcome"
    android:textColor="#E68A00"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp">
</TextView>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnsignIn_Master"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtLoginName"
    android:background="@null"
    android:gravity="right|center_horizontal"
    android:onClick="btnSignIn_onclick"
    android:text="Sign In/Sign Up"
    android:textColor="#8b8989"    
    android:textSize="12dp" >
</Button>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/iv_Arrow"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnsignIn_Master"
    android:background="@null"
    android:onClick="btnSignIn_onclick"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow1" />
```

Here is Java code:

```
Button ButtonSignInM= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnsignIn_Master);
ButtonSignInM.setText("Your Account");
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Give it a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

You probably have set the width property of the button to wrap_content. In that case, the alignment of the button may change. Use a fixed width for the button, to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have used this `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` in your xml .Remove wrap content and specify some values in it eg:`android:layout_width="20dp"`